# Issues with setting values in arrays

Tags: java

I'm new to java and making a hotel system. I have three major classes Room, Floor, and Hotel. Each floor has same type of rooms except for their room number. So I only make say 10 rooms and then give them all to my 5 floors and then assign the room number to each room in the respective floor.
The room number has its first digit as that of the floor no and the remaining digit(s) are from 1-10. 
However, all my rooms in the hotel get assigned with the 5th floor number.

Heres snippets of my code.

```
class Floor
{
    private int floorNo;
    private Room[] Rooms;

    public Floor()
    {
        floorNo = 0;
        Rooms = null;
    }

    public Floor(int f, int t)
    {
        floorNo = f;
        Rooms = new Room[t];
    }

    public void createRooms(Room[] R)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Rooms[i] = new Room();
            Rooms[i] = R[i];
        }
    }

    public void setRoom(int i, int f, int r)
    {
        Rooms[i].setFloorNo(f);
        Rooms[i].setRoomno(r);
    }

}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Room[] Rooms = new Room[10];
        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            Rooms[n] = new Room();
        }
    }

    Floor[] Floors = new Floor[5];
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
    {
        Floors[n] = new Floor(n + 1, 10);
        Floors[n].createRooms(Rooms);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Floors[n].setRoom(i, n + 1, i + 1);
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
        {
            Floors[n].print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does it even compile ? I didn't  see `total ` declared anywhere

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: does it still compile ??? You need to post exactly same code, don't put bit and pieces.

Comment: See edit.

When I call the print function for floor, it calls print for each of the room it contains. However, all the rooms are assigned the last 10 numbers. e.g 51 52 53 ... where '5' represents the floor no. The correct output should have been 11 12 13...21 22 ...

Comment: It will never compile in any of the compiler. First fix all compilation issue.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It compiles just fine. I can't post all the code due to piracy issues. :|

Comment: Can you tell me that is there a need to make a separate array of rooms for each floor (even if they are the same) or can I integrate the same array into each floor?

Comment: That `Rooms[i] = R[i];` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Floor   
{
    private int floorNo;
    private Room[] Rooms;
    public Floor()
    {
        floorNo=0;
        Rooms=null;

    }
    public Floor(int f, int t)
     {
    floorNo=f;      
    Rooms = new Room[t];

    }
    public void createRooms(Room[] R)
    {   
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i ++)
        {
        Rooms[i] = new Room();
        Rooms[i] = R[i];
        }
    }

    public void setRoom(int i, int f, int r)
    {
    Rooms[i].setFloorNo(f);
    Rooms[i].setRoomno(r,f);
    }
}

class Room
{
    public void setFloorNo(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("floor no is "+i);
    }
    public void setRoomno(int j,int k)
    {
        System.out.println("room no is "+k+""+j);
    }

}

public class main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

     Room [] Rooms= new Room[10];
     for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
     {
         Rooms[n] = new Room ();
     }

     Floor [] Floors= new Floor[5];
     for(int n=0; n<5; n++)
     {
     Floors[n] = new Floor (n+1,10);
     Floors[n].createRooms(Rooms);
     }

     for(int n=0; n < 5; n++)
     { 
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         Floors[n].setRoom(i, n+1, i+1);
    enter code here
     }
     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try smth like this:

```
public class Hotel {

    private List<Floor> floors = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addFloor(Floor floor) {
        return floors.add(floor);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int totalFloors = 5;
        int totalRoomsOnAFloor = 10;

        final Hotel hotel = new Hotel();

        int roomNumber = 0;
        for (int floorNumber = 0; floorNumber < totalFloors; floorNumber++) {
            Floor floor = new Floor(floorNumber);
            for (int floorRoomNumber = 0; floorRoomNumber < totalRoomsOnAFloor; floorRoomNumber++) {
                Room room = new Room(floor, roomNumber++);
                floor.addRoom(room);
                System.out.println("Added " + room.toString());
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Floor {

        private List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
        private int number;

        public Floor(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public boolean addRoom(Room room) {
            return rooms.add(room);
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Floor{" +
                    "number=" + number +
                    '}';
        }

    }

    public class Room {

        private final Floor floor;
        private final int number;

        public Room(Floor floor, int number) {
            this.floor = floor;
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public Floor getFloor() {
            return floor;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Room{" +
                    "number=" + number +
                    ", on the floor=" + floor +
                    '}';
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Added Room{number=0, on the floor=Floor{number=0}}
Added Room{number=1, on the floor=Floor{number=0}}
Added Room{number=2, on the floor=Floor{number=0}}
...
Added Room{number=47, on the floor=Floor{number=4}}
Added Room{number=48, on the floor=Floor{number=4}}
Added Room{number=49, on the floor=Floor{number=4}}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Actually, initial context is not even compiling, so I proposed my own implementation according to the described issue. [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom), I think is is better than nothing ))

Comment: This style of questions and answers fits better to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/